# Closing a Toplevel Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I'm trying to teach myself Python so apologies for what may be a stupid question but this has been driving me crazy for a few days. I've looked at other questions on the same subject here but still don't seem to be able to get this to work.

I have created a top level window to ask the user for a prompt and would like the window to close when the user presses the button of their choice. This is where the problem is, I can't get it to close for love or money. My code is included below.

Thank so much for any help.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

board = Frame(root)
board.pack()

square = "Chat"
cost = 2000

class buyPrompt:

         def __init__(self):
            pop = Toplevel()

            pop.title("Purchase Square")

            Msg = Message(pop, text = "Would you like to purchase %s for %d" %                         (square, cost))
            Msg.pack()


            self.yes = Button(pop, text = "Yes", command = self.yesButton)
            self.yes.pack(side = LEFT)
            self.no = Button(pop, text = "No", command = self.noButton)
            self.no.pack(side = RIGHT)

            pop.mainloop()
         def yesButton(self):
                        return True
                        pop.destroy
         def noButton(self):
                        return False
```

I've tried quite a few different ways of doing `pop.destroy` but none seem to work, things I've tried are;

```
pop.destroy()
pop.destroy
pop.exit()
pop.exit
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method to call is indeed `destroy`, on the `pop` object.

However, inside of the `yesButton` method, `pop` refers to something that is unknown.

When initializing your object, in the `__init__` method, you should put the `pop` item as an attribute of `self`:

```
self.pop = Toplevel()
```

Then, inside of your `yesButton` method, call the `destroy` method on the `self.pop` object:

```
self.pop.destroy()
```

---

About the difference between `pop.destroy` and `pop.destroy()`:

In Python, pretty much everything is an object. So a method is an object too.

When you write `pop.destroy`, you refer to the method object, named `destroy`, and belonging to the `pop` object. It's basically the same as writing `1` or `"hello"`: it's not a statement, or if you prefer, not an *action*.

When you write `pop.destroy()`, you tell Python to *call* the `pop.destroy` object, that is, to execute its `__call__` method.

In other words, writing `pop.destroy` will do nothing (except for printing something like `<bound method Toplevel.destroy of...>` when run in the interactive interpreter), while `pop.destroy()` will effectively run the `pop.destroy` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a clear and concise answer Right leg, this has solved my issue and also helped with my future knowledge when calling methods. Great answer and quick too, Thanks again